# Prove that the sequence converges to $f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that a function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R $ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$. Prove that if there exists a number $K >0$ such that
$|f'(x)| \le K$ for all $x \in (0,1)$, then the sequence $a_n=f(\frac {1}{n})$ converges to $f(0)$, $n = 1,2,3, ...$.

My attempt: Consider the sequence $a_n=f(\frac {1}{n})$ for $n \in \mathbb N $, then $ \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}f(\frac {1}{n}) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac {1}{n})= f(0)$.

Due to other information I was given about this problem, I am unsure if this is correct. Maybe it has to do something with the Mean Value Theorem: $\exists K \in(0,1),$  $f(1)-f(0)= f'(K)(1-0)$.

I would appreciate any tips or hints you can give me.

Comment: Your answer is correct! No idea why there is so much of extra information.

Comment: I agree your answer is correct.  I wonder if the intended question is to show that $f'(0)$ exists and $f'(1/n)$ converges to $f'(0)$?  (I'm not sure that my proposed change is even true, though.)

Answer (score 1):

With the MVT,
$f(\frac1{n})-f(0)
=f'(\frac{t}{n})\frac1{n}
$
where
$0 \le t \le 1$
so
$|f(\frac1{n})-f(0)|
\le \frac{K}{n}
\to 0$.